# How can I add to my previous list of tweets an another list of tweets with the function extend by using Tweepy?

Tags: tweepy

I want to be able to add a new Tweets list that contains #muteRkelly to the already created Tweets list created with #survivingRkelly.

Then, I want to be able to add a new list of tweets with #Rkelly to the two lists of tweets that will already be created with the two previous hashtags.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```py
liste_tweets = []

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#survivingRKelly",count=100, lang="en", since="2019-01-01").items(7):
    liste_tweets.append(tweet.text)
    print(liste_tweets)
    #On met une ligne pour séparer les tweets lors de la progression de la boucle
    print("---------------")

print(liste_tweets)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] your question and try format your source to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving much details here but if I understand your problem correctly you can do it for example in the following ways:

Change your search query to find 3 hashtags at once

```
liste_tweets = []

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#survivingRKelly OR #mureRkelly OR 
                                         #Rkelly",count=100, lang="en", 
                                         since="2019-01-01").items(7):
    liste_tweets.append(tweet.text)
    print(liste_tweets)
    #On met une ligne pour séparer les tweets lors de la progression de la boucle
    print("---------------")

print(liste_tweets)
```

Or if you got 2 other lists already prepared (for example you got it from a file), you can use extend

```
liste_tweets.extend(muteRKelly_list)
liste_tweets.extend(Rkelly_list)
```

Hope this helps